# Clearing Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I have been trying to get the Chrome console to clear, however it keeps giving me this 
error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Console> has no method 'clear'
```

I honestly have no idea why it keeps giving me this error. `console.log(...)` works and so do many other console functions, just not `clear()`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
         <script>
            console.log("Hello, World.");

            console.clear();
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any Ideas?

EDIT: 
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#clearing_the_console_history

states "Invoke console.clear() Console API from JavaScript." So I figured there was some way to use the clear() function from within a javascript script, but I guess I misunderstood.

Comment: Where did you see Chrome's console had a public function `clear` ?

Comment: @dystroy use `clear()` in the console.

Comment: Just do a `for(x in console) console.log(x);` and you'll see that there is no `clear()` method there.

Comment: @alex this isn't a function of console.

Comment: @dystroy - It does has a public function `clear`: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/rQwgD/

Comment: @Derek - In FF it has, in chrome it doesn't.

Comment: @Derek See the link I gave. It explains why we don't all have it (for Chrome it depends on the version). There are a few workarounds on this other question too.

Comment: @dystroy - I didn't know that it wasn't there before. :) I remember there was an old trick to clear console with hacky methods, but probably it won't work now.

Answer (score 2):

`clear()` isn't allow to be called from the page's scripts.

In the console, `clear()` can be executed. It lives at `window.console._commandLineAPI.clear` and it works in the console because it's ran in this context...

```
with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
    // console executed code
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to do it automatically? Darn.

Comment: @KyleMessner Not without assigning a reference to it from the console.

Comment: @KyleMessner, and that is done by typing this in the console: `window.clear = clear;`. You can then use `clear()`, but you'll have to execute that script in the console manually, each time you load a page.